# What is the difference between lookback period and transform a time series dataset into a supervised learning dataset for time-series forecasting?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, regression, forecasting

Let's say I have [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18PGLNnOI44LVFignYriBWQFW9WBkTX5c/view?usp=share_link) within the following [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) dataframe format with a *non-standard* timestamp column without datetime format as follows:

```
+--------+-----+
|TS_24hrs|count|
+--------+-----+
|0       |157  |
|1       |334  |
|2       |176  |
|3       |86   |
|4       |89   |
 ...      ...
|270     |192  |
|271     |196  |
|270     |251  |
|273     |138  |
+--------+-----+
274 rows × 2 columns
```

The dataset shape is $274*2$ and contains the first column of `timestamp` and 2nd column of numerical statistical `count` as the label, and I want to train some ML\DL regression models and do ***out-of-sample prediction*** (predicting beyond the training dataset) over future data (**unseen test-set**). I have already implemented RF regression within [sklearn](/questions/tagged/sklearn) `pipeline()` after splitting data with the following strategy for 274 records:

> - split data into [*training-set* + *validation-set*] [Ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59452915/10452700) *e.g. The first 200 records [160 +40]*
> - keeping **unseen** [*test-set*] hold-on for final forecasting *e.g. The last 74 records (after 200th rows\event)*

```py
#print(train.shape)          #(160, 2)
#print(validation.shape)     #(40, 2)
#print(test.shape)           #(74, 2)
```

[image: img]

- [lookback period](https://machinelearningmastery.com/lstm-for-time-series-prediction-in-pytorch/), [example1](https://towardsdatascience.com/one-step-predictions-with-lstm-forecasting-hotel-revenues-c9ef0d3ef2df), [example2](https://www.kaggle.com/code/hassanamin/time-series-analysis-using-lstm-keras/notebook)

```py
#ِDataset matrix is formed
def create_dataset(df , lookback=1):
  data  = np.array(df.iloc[:, :-1])
  label = np.array(df.iloc[:, -1])
  #create X_train and Y_train and MinMaxScaler on Y_train
  X = list()
  Y = list()
  for i in range(lookback , len(data)):
      X.append(data[i-lookback:i])
      Y.append(label[i])
  X = np.array(X)
  Y = np.array(Y)
  Y=np.expand_dims(Y,-1) 
  return X,Y

# Lookback period
lookback = 5
X_train, Y_train = create_dataset(train, lookback)
X_val, Y_val = create_dataset(validation, lookback)
X_test, Y_test = create_dataset(test, lookback)
# print(X_train.shape , Y_train.shape)       #(155, 5, 1) (155, 1)
# print(X_val.shape, Y_val.shape)            #(35, 5, 1) (35, 1)
# print(X_test.shape, Y_test.shape)          #(69, 5, 1) (69, 1)
```

- [transform a time series dataset into a supervised learning dataset](https://machinelearningmastery.com/random-forest-for-time-series-forecasting/) posted by *Jason Brownlee*:

```py
# Finalize the model and make a prediction for monthly births with random forest
from numpy import asarray
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import concat
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
 
# transform a time series dataset into a supervised learning dataset
def series_to_supervised(data, n_in=1, n_out=1, dropnan=True):
 n_vars = 1 if type(data) is list else data.shape[1]
 df = DataFrame(data)
 cols = list()
 # input sequence (t-n, ... t-1)
 for i in range(n_in, 0, -1):
 cols.append(df.shift(i))
 # forecast sequence (t, t+1, ... t+n)
 for i in range(0, n_out):
 cols.append(df.shift(-i))
 # put it all together
 agg = concat(cols, axis=1)
 # drop rows with NaN values
 if dropnan:
 agg.dropna(inplace=True)
 return agg.values
 
# load the dataset
series = read_csv('daily-total-female-births.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
values = series.values
# transform the time series data into supervised learning
train = series_to_supervised(values, n_in=6)
# split into input and output columns
trainX, trainy = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1]
# fit model
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000)
model.fit(trainX, trainy)
# construct an input for a new prediction
row = values[-6:].flatten()
# make a one-step prediction
yhat = model.predict(asarray([row]))
print('Input: %s, Predicted: %.3f' % (row, yhat[0]))
```

**Qs:**

**Q1:** What is the difference between these two approaches? (*lookback period* Vs *transform a time series dataset into a supervised learning dataset*)
I also tried in meantime `walk_forward_validation()` approach inspired from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69442740/multivariate-xgboost-time-series):

> Walk forward validation is a method for **estimating the skill of the model on out of sample data.** We contrive out of sample and each time step one out of sample observation becomes in-sample. We can use the same model in ops, as long as the walk-forward is performed each time a new observation is received.

My observation shows no difference between using:

- just `series_to_supervised` (STS)
- `walk_forward_validation` (WFV) & `series_to_supervised` (STS) comparing outputs, especially MAE results, but a bit in quality of forecasting up & downs(could be due to weights during training):

[image: img]

**Q2:** How possibly can I reflect\compare prediction results when data split size based on my strategy has undergone of above methods, e.g. *Look back period* while `lookback = 5`? (I already missed 5 records, and in practice leads **delay** in forecasting the right point)

````py
# The first 200 records slice for training-set and validation-set
df200=df[:200]          

# The rest records = 74 events (after 200th event) kept as hold-on unseen-set for forcasting
test = df[200:]                                   #test

# Split the data into training and testing sets

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train, validation = train_test_split(df200 , test_size=0.2, shuffle=False) #train + validation
#print(train.shape)          #(160, 2)
#print(validation.shape)     #(40, 2)
#print(test.shape)           #(74, 2)
```
````